# How to call a SQL function inside package body of another function

Tags: sql, oracle, package, sql-function

I have a package body as give bellow. I need to call a function named TESTING() inside the function body and call another query. Code is given bellow

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST_PCAKAGE AS  -- body
  FUNCTION OUTER_FUNCTION (
    INPUT_A  IN VARCHAR2,
    INPUT_B  IN DATE,
  ) RETURN REF_CURSOR_TYPE  IS
    CUR_CA_RECEIPTS REF_CURSOR_TYPE;
  BEGIN
     OPEN CUR_CA_RECEIPTS FOR
       TESTING();
         SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE;
         RETURN CUR_CA_RECEIPTS;
       END OUTER_FUNCTION;
END TEST_PCAKAGE ;
```

**when creating this package body, it gives me errors. Can anyone please tell me how to do this?**

Error : Error(14,1): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

```
create or replace
FUNCTION           "TESTING" RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN('SUCCESS');
END;
```

Comment: What exact errors do you receive? Where at least on semicolon missing after calling TESTING: `RESULT:=TESTING(INPUT_A, INPUT_B);` and no END IF; statement

Comment: I have update the question. Please check now

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you'r trying to return the cursor from the function

Try this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST_PCAKAGE AS  -- body
  FUNCTION OUTER_FUNCTION (
    INPUT_A  IN VARCHAR2,
    INPUT_B  IN DATE,
  ) RETURN REF_CURSOR_TYPE  IS
    -- use sys_refcursor for dynamic cursors 
    CUR_CA_RECEIPTS sys_refcursor;
  BEGIN
     -- Open the cursor for a query and not a function
     OPEN CUR_CA_RECEIPTS FOR SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE;
     -- i'm guessing this is for debug
     TESTING();
     -- you can now iterate it in a different procedure
     RETURN CUR_CA_RECEIPTS;
  END OUTER_FUNCTION;
END TEST_PCAKAGE ;
```

Comment: Getting an error : Error(17,1): PLS-00221: 'TESTING' is not a procedure or is undefined

Comment: i dont know what `testing()` is ....  i figured it's a function you have in your db. what are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: I have edited the question and put the testing function. Actually what I need is to call the testing() first and if the function returns 'success' I want to call the select query and return data